# Floating point values: in memory vs. in register?

Tags: floating-point

In [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), it is mentioned that:

> While debugging, values that an optimized program would normally keep
>   in registers are often pushed to main memory. This may affect, for
>   instance, the result of **floating-point** comparisons, since the value **in
>   memory** may have smaller range and accuracy than the value in the
>   **register**.

However, as far as I know, in IEEE 754, the representation of a floating point value 
should be fixed, and I suppose this representation won't change in either memory or 
register?

So, does the difference appear in some special cases? Actually my understanding is limited
in 32 and 64 bit machines.

Comment: This is a general comment on a general case. Specific implementations will differ in their effects. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @MikeW ah, I just couldn't think of a case when an implementation is that 'specific', and so sad the keywords find no valuable information from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some Intel processors, for example, the floating point registers are 80 bits wide, but the C language types are the regular 32- and 64-bit `float` and `double` types.  Just like your quotation, says, "in memory the *(32- or 64-bit)* value has smaller range and accuracy than the *(80-bit)* value in the register."